# Applying stroke style to TTF font

Tags: fonts, bitmap, photoshop

Is there a program out there that I can take an existing TTF file and add a black outline stroke like in Photoshop and then export it out again as either a TTF or a bitmap font?

Edit: Actually if it can be converted to TTF as I can use AngelCodes to make a bitmap font with stroke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible add stroke for ttf files. You can use drop shadow property of the Label. For bitmap font, you can add effect on the png file with out making any modification in letters positions.